# Loading razor components dynamically in blazor application

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I am trying to load multiple razor components in my blazor application. The current page is having some dictionary object filled dynamically. Just for illustration purpose I am using Employee class example. I know which component I have to load, so I don't need , but loading custom component in loop.

```
private Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<Employee>> employees;

@foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    <EmployeeComponent DeptId="@employee.Key" @bind-Emp="@employee.Value" SomeEvent="EmpIdChanged" />
}@
```

Is there any downside of this approach considering performance. There could be 10 to 15 employees at max. Or suggest any better approach to do this.

Comment: Why not using foreach in blazor component,and pass the whole list to component?So that you only need to load a razor component.

Comment: Not really with 10-15.  I have similar implementations in a lot of data views where there are 100+ components - one for each column in each row in say a 25 row paged grid.

Comment: @YiyiYou Good suggestion and your thinking is right. May be because I did not choose the correct example. However actually consider that I am loading employees from different companies. And each company has it's tab. So when I load EmployeeComponent, it will be loaded as separate tab for each company. That's why I want a foreach on component not inside component. Tx

Comment: I forgot to complete my sentence above <so I don't need "dynamicomponent">.

Comment: So consider requirement like this: Continent based companies and their data. User selects continent then you load 7-8 companies, each in separate tab. Each tab has grid with company data. If continent is changed you load different 10-12 companies specific to selected continent. Company data n sequence is dynamic.

Comment: If you need to use different razor components for employees,I think  loading multiple razor components  is better.

Comment: @YiyiYou No, I am not intend to load different components, I will be loading same component for every company (no different component for employees too).